# Linked Server Provider

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, oledb

Attempting to set up a linked server to a Oracle 11g database via MSSQL 2016.

Unfortunately I don't seem to have **any** data providers to choose from in SSMS. Initially thought it was an issue with configuring the oracle client, however from my research I believe there should be some providers here by default.

[image]

I can see and set up the oracle data provider in the windows ODBC 64 bit Data Sources configuration window - so believe this is configured correctly.

[image]

SQL Server Version is:
"Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) - 13.0.5201.2 (X64)   Aug 18 2018 07:38:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)"

Output of `EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop` returns no result rows.

Comment: What permissions do you have on the server? Are you a sysadmin or setupadmin?

Comment: Hi HandyD - the above screenshot was taken with sysadmin permissions.